# How to be able to process a large JSON response?

Tags: json, rest, governorlimits

We're calling an external REST service from Salesforce and are receiving a JSON response of more than 45 MB. Has anyone attempted anything like this?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are calling a Salesforce REST service from an external client or you are calling an external REST service from within Salesforce (apex)?

Comment: @JayantDas I have added clarification to my question.

Comment: Thanks. Had thought that you are calling from Salesforce but good to get that clarified. Derek's answer is what I would think addresses this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's just no way to cram that much data into Salesforce as-is.

I'd imagine you'd need to introduce a layer in the middle to break that JSON up into more manageable pieces, and also make use of async processing (probably using Queueable).

As I'm sure you know, the transaction limit on heap size is 6MB (12MB Async), and that space needs to hold the incoming response, store it again (plus overhead) when you deserialize it, and have space left over to do whatever processing you need to do.

Another option would be to have the middle layer (Heroku, some VM on some cloud provider, etc...) do the processing for you, and then create/update/delete whatever it is that you need to do via accessing Salesforce's APIs

Comment: I like your suggestion of having the middle layer call Salesforce's APIs. I don't know if the middle layer will be able to handle that kind of load. An alternative would be to have the middle layer implement a paging mechanism, but this would also mean more work on the Salesforce side.

Comment: I also think that doing tens of thousands of REST calls to Salesforce will not be as efficient as processing 45 times 1 MB JSON files, for example.

Comment: @SanderdeJong Depending on what precisely you're doing, you could create multiple records in Salesforce with a single request, or use the _composite_ resource to package up multiple API calls into a single call.

Answer (score 0):

In Apex, no chance. The maximum response size is limited to 6/12/36MB (depending on context). You'd have to do client-side processing (e.g. Visualforce via the [AJAX Proxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_proxy.htm)) in order to handle this amount of data.